# How to enable spell check in Notes?

Tags: macos, notes.app, spellcheck

I want to enable the option **Check spelling while typing** in macOS Notes app.

This is usually done in:
**Notes** > **Edit** > **Spelling and Grammar** > **Check spelling while typing**.

But, I cannot. For some reason, this just does not work for Notes (for other applications it does).

Does anyone know how to **force** this setup in Notes via command line (Terminal)? or any other workaround?

Comment: What about it doesn't work?